# How to display common taxonomy terms from 2 diffrent vacabulary in views

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

I have 2 vocabulary and this vocabulary used in content type. I want to display common terms from different vocabulary.

1) Basechart taxonomy:
   - Alphabets 
   - ASER 
   - Story
   - ASER(D)

2) Endchart taxonomy:
   - Alphabets 
   - ASER 
   - Story
   - ASER(D)

Now my result displaying this:
Name       Mark1       Mark2 
Alphabets      1             0

Alphabets      0             1

Story             2             2

ASER            0             1

ASER            1             0

ASER(D)       0             1

ASER(D)       1             0

I want to display below result:
Name       Mark1       Mark2 
Alphabets      1             1

Story             2             2

ASER            1             1

ASER(D)       1             1

Comment: Are you using views or doing it programmatically?

Comment: I am using views.